# How to speed up tramp with ivy

Tags: tramp, completion, ivy, performance, remote

I use ivy for file and buffer completion.

As soon as I have *one* (dired) buffer which gets its content via tramp from a (slow) remote server all buffer and file selection commands become very slow even if all of the displayed buffers/directories are local.

Any way to tell tramp/ivy not to bother about non-displayed buffers/directories